# Setting up a global string

Tags: android, global-variables, onactivityresult

Hopefully this explains it better.
So I have 10 clases that do essentially the same thing.
Each class has ten buttons, each button starts a speech recognition intent, and a startActivityForResult.

The onClickListeners and onAcitivityResults are on a GlobalListener class, which is extended by each of the 10 Activities.

below is code from the 'GlobalListener.java'

```
       public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            Intent a = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            a.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak now.");
            startActivityForResult(a, checka);

            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case R.id.button2:
            Intent b = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            b.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Now.");
            startActivityForResult(b, checkb);
```

In this same class I have the onActivityResult

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == checka && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results =      data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        if(results.contains("apples") || results.contains("tree") ||     results.contains("house") || results.contains("big house")|| results.contains("big tree")||     results.contains("big apple tree")){
            /////Do  something

if (requestCode == checkb && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        if(results.contains("oranges") || results.contains("orange tree") || results.contains("orange house")|| results.contains("big orange house")|| results.contains("big orange tree")){ ///
```

Im having a hard time trying to build global string to match this argument.

```
if(results.contains("apples") || results.contains("tree") || results.contains("house") || results.contains("big house")|| results.contains("small house")|| results.contains("big tree"))
```

Since each of these 10 activities extends the same GlobalListener, I needed to change what the GlobalListener is "listening" for at runtime, depending on which of these 10 activities is being called. So I created a `GlobalVariables` class

```
public class GlobalVariables {
 private static GlobalVariables instance;

static {
    instance = new GlobalVariables();
}

private GlobalVariables() {
}

public static GlobalVariables getInstance() {
    return GlobalVariables.instance;
}

private String someVariable;

public String getSomeVariable() {
    return someVariable;
}

public void setSomeVariable(String someVariable) {
    this.someVariable = someVariable;
}
```

So on my main Activity1 I set it like this..

```
 public class Activity1 extends GlobalListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    GlobalVariables.getInstance().setSomeVariable("apples");
```

On my GlobalListener class where I have my OnActivityResult, and I change it from

```
       if(results.contains("apples") || ////
```

to

```
   if(results.contains(GlobalVariables.getInstance().getSomeVariable()) || ///
```

This works, but it means I have to create;

-a global String for each acceptable result on the onActivityResult

-set the string in my Main class

-then on my onActivityResult do results.contains(lobalVariables.getInstance().getSomeVariable2()) etc

Im not so much concerned with the time in writing it this way,but rather in learning to do things more efficiently, cleaner.
I guess learning how to build a global string array with an argument?

thanks

Comment: Please study and learn what `static` means in relation to OOP.  There are too many problems in this question to address effectively.  You should also read about the `singleton` pattern.  Also question why you need a globally static string.  It usually indicates a fault in the design.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve? I cannot really figure out from what you wrote above and there's quite likely an easier way. We need to understand better to help you.

Comment: OK, thanks.. I will re-read them. I have read about `static` in OOP and the `singleton` pattern and the discussions of `singleton` vs `extending Application`, pros and cons..clearly I must have missed or misunderstood something.. thanks again

Comment: @Szymon Ok I'll edit the question and hopefully explain it better, thanks

Comment: @Simon Hey Simon, thanks again for the feedback, so I read some more on static and its usage/avoidance in OOP..from what  gather I could generate a memory leak by holding a reference to it? Any who I posted more of the code, if u ever get a chance and have time to clarify a bit the many problems in my approach, Im all ears..thanks